# How to fix 'X is not a class template' when dealing with ints in struct templates?

Tags: c++

I can't get my code to compile, I'm trying have a class which stores information about types using a struct template which accepts an int and a parameter pack.

```
#include <tuple>
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <vector>

template<int N, typename... Ts>
    struct type_info_impl<N, Ts...> {
    typedef typename std::tuple_element<N, std::tuple<Ts...>>::type type;
    static const size_t size = sizeof(type);
};

template<typename... Types>
class type_info {
    public:
      type_info(){}
      ~type_info(){}

      template<int N>
      static constexpr size_t size(){
        return type_info_impl<N, Types...>::size;
      }
};

using types = type_info<bool, int, double>;

using namespace std;

int main()
{

   cout << types::size<1>() << endl; 

   return 0;
}
```

The number "4" should be outputted since the size of the type (int) at index 1 is 4 but it instead throws "‘type_info_impl’ is not a class template
     struct type_info_impl {"

Comment: Typo? `struct type_info_impl<N, Ts...>` -> `struct type_info_impl`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are using to define `type_info_impl` is wrong.

Use of

```
template<int N, typename... Ts>
    struct type_info_impl<N, Ts...> { ...};
```

is OK if you are trying to specialize the class template. To define the basic class template, remove the `<N, Ts...>` bit. Just use

```
template<int N, typename... Ts>
    struct type_info_impl { ...};
```

Comment: What would I need to do if I have other `type_info_impl` templates in the file and I want to specialize the template? For example `template<typename T, typename... Ts>` which accepts the type instead of its position?

Comment: @CheyenneForbesdeAvapno, all specialization are required to use the first form.